# Leaflet geoJSON not valid however it is

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to add some PHP / Mysql generated JSON data onto a leaflet map however it is throwing leaflet.js:5 Uncaught Error: Invalid GeoJSON object. however upon validation on JSONLint it says the geojson is valid any advice would be much appreciated thanks. I can't seem to figure out what the problem may be.

Map Load

```
     $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'results.json',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (response) {
    geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(response).addTo(mymap);
    mymap.fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds());
    $("#info").fadeOut(500);
}
});
```

GeoJSON generation

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost";    
$database = "c9";
// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ($hostname, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}
// json output - insert table name below after "FROM"
$query = 'SELECT * FROM crimes';
$dbquery = mysql_query($query);
if(! $dbquery )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
// Parse the dbquery into geojson 
// ================================================
// ================================================
// Return markers as GeoJSON
$geojson = array(
    'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
 );
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbquery)) {
    $feature = array(
        'category' => $row['crime'],
      'location' => array(
        'coordinates' => array((float)$row['Latitude'],(float)$row['Longitude'])
            ),
        'streetname' => $row['streetname'],
        'crimeID' => $row['crimeID'],
        'resolution' => $row['resolution'],
        'outcomedate' => $row['outcomedate']

        );
    array_push($geojson, $feature);
};
mysql_close($connection);
// // Return routing result
    header("Content-Type:application/json",true);
    echo json_encode($geojson);
    $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($geojson));
fclose($fp);
header("Location: ../add_crime.php");
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "0": {
        "category": "antisocialbehaviour",
        "location": {
            "coordinates": [53.8008, 1.5491]
        },
        "streetname": "street test",
        "crimeID": "1",
        "resolution": "localres",
        "outcomedate": "2015-05-05"
    },
    "1": {
        "category": "Arson",
        "location": {
            "coordinates": [53.8008, 1.5491]
        },
        "streetname": "60 st wilfrids grove",
        "crimeID": "2",
        "resolution": "Offender deprived of property",
        "outcomedate": "2015-05-05"
    },
    "2": {
        "category": "Arson",
        "location": {
            "coordinates": [53.8008, 1.5491]
        },
        "streetname": "60 st wilfrids grove",
        "crimeID": "3",
        "resolution": "Offender deprived of property",
        "outcomedate": "2015-05-05"
    },
    "3": {
        "category": "Arson",
        "location": {
            "coordinates": [53.8008, 1.5491]
        },
        "streetname": "Rookwood Road",
        "crimeID": "4",
        "resolution": "Offender deprived of property",
        "outcomedate": "2015-05-05"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

GeoJSON format is a particular type of JSON format.

It has its [own specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946), and the sample data you exhibit is not compliant with that spec.

You can see an example of a compliant GeoJSON object here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-1.5

```json
{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [{
       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry": {
           "type": "Point",
           "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]
       },
       "properties": {
           "prop0": "value0"
       }
   }, {
       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry": {
           "type": "LineString",
           "coordinates": [
               [102.0, 0.0],
               [103.0, 1.0],
               [104.0, 0.0],
               [105.0, 1.0]
           ]
       },
       "properties": {
           "prop0": "value0",
           "prop1": 0.0
       }
   }, {
       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry": {
           "type": "Polygon",
           "coordinates": [
               [
                   [100.0, 0.0],
                   [101.0, 0.0],
                   [101.0, 1.0],
                   [100.0, 1.0],
                   [100.0, 0.0]
               ]
           ]
       },
       "properties": {
           "prop0": "value0",
           "prop1": {
               "this": "that"
           }
       }
   }]
}
```

You have several dedicated GeoJSON linting tool, e.g. http://geojsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how would I generate this via PHP I'm struggling to adjust the code, thanks.

Comment: Ask a new question with PHP tag for this specific issue, you would very probably get a better answer that way.